# If we assume merely that the partials $D_jf$ exist in a neighborhood of $a$ and are continuous at $a$ then $f$ is differentiable in $a$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

**Show that the proof of Theorem $6.2$ goes through if we assume merely that the partials $D_jf$ exist in a neighborhood of $a$ and are continuous at $a$ then $f$ is differentiable in $a$.**

**Theorem $6.2.$** *Let $A$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Suppose that the partial
derivatives $D_jf_i(x)$ of the component functions of $f$ exist at each point
$x$ of $A$ and are continuous on $A$. Then $f$ is differentiable at each point
of $A$.*

I am reading the book "Analysis on manifolds" by Munkres and in the proposed exercises this problem is found, I have already thought a lot about this problem and I know that there are many related posts on this site about this, but I would like someone to explain to me how this can be demonstrated and how this can be applied to a particular problem by means of an example, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is straightforward, but notationally messy.

First notice that it is sufficient to deal with $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$.

It is easy to guess the candidate derivative as $h \mapsto \sum_k {\partial f(x) \over \partial x_k} h_k$ (the sum is taken over
$k=1,...,n$).

Now you need to find an appropriate estimate of $\|f(x+h)-f(x) - \sum_k {\partial f(x) \over \partial x_k} h_k\|$.

Let $\phi_k(h) = (h_1,\cdots,h_k,0,\cdots)$, with $\phi_0(h) = 0$.

We can write $f(x+h)-f(x) = \sum_k f(x+\phi_k(h))-f(x+\phi_{k-1}(h))$.

Note that $(x+\phi_k(h))-(x+\phi_{k-1}(h)) = h_k e_k$, where $e_k$
is the standard $k$th unit vector $(\cdots, 0,1,0, \cdots)$.

Apply the mean value theorem to get
$f(x+\phi_k(h))-f(x+\phi_{k-1}(h)) = {\partial f(x+\phi_{k-1}(h)+ \xi_k e_k) \over \partial x_k} h_k$, where $|\xi_k| \le |h_k|$.

Hence we have the estimate
$f(x+h)-f(x) - \sum_k {\partial f(x) \over \partial x_k} h_k = \sum_k ({\partial f(x+\phi_{k-1}(h)+ \xi_k e_k) \over \partial x_k}-{\partial f(x) \over \partial x_k}) h_k$, again with
$|\xi_k| \le |h_k|$.

Now choose $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\delta>0$ such that if the
$|h_k| < \delta$, then
$|{\partial f(x+\phi_{k-1}(h)+ \xi_k e_k) \over \partial x_k}-{\partial f(x) \over \partial x_k}| < {1 \over n} \epsilon$.
We can do this because the partials are continuous at $x$.

Comment: Why  it is sufficient to deal with $f:A→\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If real valued $f_1,\cdots,f_m$ are differentiable, then $(f_1,\cdots,f_m)$ is.

Comment: @copper.hat Why is that the candidate to be the derivative? here $h=(h_1,...,h_k,...)$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The derivative is a linear operator. I realise that $h\in \mathbb{R}^m$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Assume the partial derivatives of $f$ exist in the open unit disc and are continuous at $(0,0).$  Then by the MVT,

$$f(x,y)= f(0,0) +f(x,0)-f(0,0) + f(x,y)-f(x,0)$$ $$ = f(0,0) + \partial f/\partial x(c_x,0)\cdot x + \partial f/\partial y(x,c(x,y))\cdot y.$$

Use this to show $Df(0,0)$ exists.

Comment: Don't you need to know that $f$ absolutely continuous (along each coordinate) to do this?

Comment: @copper.hat  let's see: $f$ is differentiable in the one variable sense on each line parallel to the axes, but that doesn't mean we can use the ordinary FTC. However, the $L^1$ FTC shows that what I wrote is correct. But that is too much machinery to use here. So thanks for your comment. I see now that the MVT is the way go here.

Comment: I'm grinding through a MVT version... Good observation re. the $L_1$ FTC, if it had occurred to me I would have done the same.

Comment: @zhw. Do you do it with $(0,0)$ because one takes any point of the plane and can transfer it to the origin?

Comment: @user424241 I do it just for simplicity. Yes, the argument is transferable to any point.

Comment: @zhw. To show that $Df(0,0)$ exists, could I say that $Df(0,0)=(D_1f(0,0),D_2f(0,0))=(\partial f/\partial x(0,0), \partial f/\partial y(0,0))$ and so how would I find $\partial f/\partial x(0,0)$ and $\partial f/\partial y(0,0)$ with respect to the answer you have given?

Comment: @user424241You don't have to find them; it's given they exist. Call them $a,b$ respectively. You know that if $Df(0,0)$ exists, it has the form $Df(0,0) = ax + by.$ So write $$f(0,0) + \partial f/\partial x(c_x,0)\cdot x + \partial f/\partial y(x,c(x,y))\cdot y = f(0,0) + ax + b y + (\partial f/\partial x(c_x,0)-a) x + (\partial f/\partial y(x,c(x,y)- b)y $$